# How to redirect user to his profile using unique link in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a Rails app using mongodb. I have a model **Bot** with an attribute **link** (string). I want user to redirect to its profile using unique link which consists of host and link (e.g. http://localhost:3000/bots/home/06b5f629b3fbec5612ef79dd14d8d762).

**routes.rb**

```
get 'bots/home/:link' => 'bots#home'
```

**bots_controller.rb**

```
 def home
    @hu = request.url[32..-1]
    @bots = Bot.where(link: @hu)
  end
```

So I try to retrieve this unique value from request and match it to **link** attribute of the **Bot** in db but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you define `:link` why are you manually poking into the request URL? In any case, define "doesn't work".

Comment: Because I want user to sign in using unique link and have to match part of the url with the link.

Comment: Why not use `params[:link]` instead of this defensive method?

Comment: Can you help me please with this, I'm new to Rails. How should I write it in routes and controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, use that `:link` param,  you are sending all named and clean to your controller.

Then, I guess you are trying to get one Bot,  not a collection of Bots. If you are after a collection of Bots, your syntax is fine, else add `.first` after your `where`

So,  your method should look something like this, without digging deep into political correctness:

```
def home
     @bots = Bot.where(link:params[:link])
end
```